# Why is my function to Reverse an array not working?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, recursion

Wrote a recursive function to reverse an array but its producing the same array. why?

```
def reverseArray(arr):
    l=0
    r=len(arr)-1
    if l<r:
        arr[l],arr[r] = arr[r], arr[l]
        reverseArray(arr[l+1:r])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr = [-1, -1, 6, 1, 9, 3, 2, -1, 4, -1]
    reverseArray(arr)
    print(arr)
```

Comment: why not just `print(arr[::-1])` or `arr.reverse()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr[l+1:r]` creates a copy of the original array. So your original array will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

if you're interested in a recursive approach you can use

```
def reverse_helper(A, start, end):
    if start >= end:
        return
    A[start], A[end] = A[end], A[start]
    reverse_helper(A, start+1, end-1)

def reverse(A):
    return reverse_helper(A,0,len(A)-1)
```

Or

```py
def reverse(t):
  if not t:
    return []
  else
    return [ *reverse(t[1:]), t[0] ]
```